# video live streaming application in React Native

Tags: react-native, video-streaming, live-streaming

I am trying to implement video live streaming

- live streaming and
- upload it to server and
- save the streaming video (Playback)

in react native can any one help me with a sample project

Answer (score 0):

this is will be helpful `https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-video`

for point `upload it to server`, what exactly do u need upload? video uploading or something else?

Comment: *I need it like facebook live streaming after stoping the the live we should get the live streaming video

Comment: or Like team meeting , if we record the meeting after ending the meeting we are getting the recorded video

Comment: then you can try Elemental Medialive for livestream

Comment: any sample code to implement in react native or any reference

Answer (score 0):

So - you'll need a backend server that can accept a video stream, and convert it into a stream that can be consumed in React Native.  You'd also like the server to save the streamed video, and encode it so it can be played back as video on demand (VOD) after the stream has stopped. None of this is React - it'll all be done on the backend.

You can build all this yourself, but there are a number of APIs that can do this for you.  Disclaimer: I work for one such company: [api.video](https://api.video). (A Google search will find others)

For livestreaming from the browser, you can use getUserMedia and stream to a server. (you can see my demo using JavaScript at [livestream.a.video](https://livestream.a.video).  This stream wil be visible to all your users, and then also recorded and saved as VOD for later playback.

To upload a recorded video - you can use file.slice() to break the video into manageable chunks, and upload to the server - for transcoding into a video stream (demo at [upload.a.video](https://upload.a.video), and [tutorial](https://api.video/blog/tutorials/uploading-large-files-with-javascript).)

For playback, these APIs will give you a player URL or the m3u8 url that you can incorporate into a video player.  This is your React Native part - and there are several video players that you can add into your application to playback HLS video.  At api.video, we have our own player, and also support [3rd party players](https://api.video/blog/tutorials/using-api-video-with-external-video-players).